# Python argparse fails when the script run without preceding py -2 or -3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, command-line, argparse

My python code is:

```
# my_script.py

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.verbose:
    print("verbosity turned on")
```

My default python is `Python 3.7.4` (also python 2 is installed on my PC). When I run this script from Windows command line this way:

```
py -2 my_script.py
```

or this way:

```
py -3 my_script.py
```

The script works fine. But when I run this way:

```
my_script.py
```

I get the next error:

```
usage: my_script.py [-h] [-v]
my_script.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
```

Why? I always run all my python scripts without preceding `py` and it works (they do not include `argparse` module)

Can you please help - why python script that contains `arparse` does not run without preceding `py`?

Comment: Try typing 'where my_script' to see if you are accidentally running another version of my_script.py that is located on your path.

Comment: Is `my_scirpt.py` the actual output or is it a typo?

Comment: Hi Axe319, it's a typo - fixing

Comment: It is likely that the command associated with `.py` in the registry is introducing the error.